What is a port?
I have been running an Apache web server for numerous years and have been using ports as a medium to serve requests.
Recently, I began using Unix sockets to serve MySQL requests. The function of Unix sockets I understand as:

the 'socket' is a specific location in memory, represented as a system file with extension '.sock'. When used as a communication medium, a process can write to (or read from) this file to communicate with another process.

What, and where, are system ports ?
Do files exist in the filesystem that facilitate the same communication purpose as Unix sockets ?
If I wish to interface with, say, port 80, and interpret a HTTP request, how could I achieve that ?

TCP and UDP both have a concept of numbered "ports" for identifying different sessions (tasks) using those protocols, and there are those customary well-known ports for servers, like TCP port 80 for HTTP. But I'm not sure if you mean those when you say "system ports", or if you mean something else. Also note that TCP port 80 is not the same as UDP port 80, as those are two different protocols, even if they both have a very similar concept of a "port".

Specifically, when I use software (such as Apache), Apache receives requests over, say, 'port 80'. This request is a string containing HTTP headers and other info. If I was to access this myself, how would I ? Unix sockets communicate via '.sock' files - where do ports communicate via ?

A socket is an abtraction layer for connectivity and communication.  They come in various forms or "domains"; common ones are AF_UNIX (or AF_LOCAL), which is the type of socket you were using for MySQL, and AF_INET and AF_INET6, for ipv4/ipv6 connections.  Others are possible; see man 2 socket for a list.
Within each domain there are options; a "type" and a "protocol".  What these mean may vary across the different domains.
And then a socket can be bound to an address; this address also varies across the domain.  For a Unix domain socket this would be a path name (which can be any pathname, it need not end with .sock).  For an ipv4/ipv6 socket this could be an IP address and a port number (which is a number between 1 and 65535; various services use "well known" ports; eg a webserver may be on port 80 and 443).
This abstraction layer makes it relatively easy to write a "standard" type of server.  It would do something like

create a socket with socket()
bind the socket to an address with bind()
listen on the socket with listen()
loop around accepting connections with accept() and processing the request.

A client is a bit simpler:

create a socket with socket()
connect to the server with connect()

What goes into the socket(), bind(), connect() calls will depend on the domain and type of socket you want.

From your explanation above, I believe it is the binding phase I am interested in. Checking my understanding: for the specific case of a Unix OS, communication 'mediums' are always files in the filesystem. Is the specific file determined by the kernel function bind() ? For example, I could write a bash script, call bind and set the communication 'medium' to be, say, /myfile.extension and the port to be, say, 'port x' ? Then, the kernel will write incoming data, attempting to connect to 'port x', to the file /myfile.extension ?

No.  When you bind() a socket, you pick the address.  For a Unix  domain socket that would be a file system path entry; for an IP domain socket that would be an IP address and a  port.   An IP domain socket does not have a filesystem entry at all.   And you probably wouldn't do this in bash; that's totally the wrong tool for the job.

@user10709800 Adding to Stephen's answer:  See: List of TCP and UDP port numbers.  A bit of help for your clarification.  Think of that port list, I just linked, as virtual sockets.  Neither end of an HTTP request ever exist on either servers filesystem,  Think of sockets as communication pathways between multiple applications on the same filesystem, i.e systemd logging (the application that writes a log creates a socket, and the logging program has a socket. To "write" the log entry one socket sends and one receives
